# Open Vent under roof overhang

Tags: bathroom, roof, exhaust-fan, exhaust-vent

I am trying to help with my parents home maintenance since my dad’s stroke. They have this open vent under their roof overhang. I assume it is for a bathroom exhaust, but I don’t know what to replace it with. It also looks like it’s riveted into the metal, how would I affix a replacement? Guidance on the process would be greatly appreciated.
[image: image of open vent on roof]

Comment: The only thing it needs is maybe a screen to keep out birds and rodents.

Comment: Do you want to just replace it with a new one?  You can get a round soffit vent that's basically a short tube with a flanged grille.

Comment: The hot moist air coming out of the vent will rise up and go in through the adjacent soffit vent slots (leading to possible mold/rot issues inside attic), so I would at least cover up the soffit vent slots in those two strips right next to the outlet opening.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing it needs is a screen to keep out birds and rodents. Put 1/4 inch mesh "hardwre cloth" over it and screw it to the soffit or the trim piece with the large washers with a small hole.

If you don't want to screw into anthing, fold the corners of the piece of hardware cloth up or down to allow insertion into the fitting.

Comment: There are also screened inserts which just plug into the standard sized opening.